# ACF - How do I use exported field groups in a PHP file rather than in the CMS?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a site with WordPress and using Advanced Custom Fields Pro (ACF) to create custom field groups. I would rather have my field groups exported and in ACF PHP files rather than using it in the CMS.

Within my theme, my `functions.php` file is at the root level, and my ACF files are in `library/acf/acf-file.php`.

How can I link these ACF files so that I can use them on my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If you want to import fields exported as php arrays

Once you generated the export code from the ACF admin page :

1. Create a new .php file in a conveniant place inside your theme's folder, and paste the generated content. It should look like something like this :

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):
  acf_add_local_field_group(array ());
endif;
```

2. In your theme's `functions.php` file, include the previously created file

```
include_once('my_acf_fields.php');
```

#### If you want to import fields exported as a json file

Once you generated the json file from the ACF admin page :

1. Add the generated .json file in a conveniant place inside your theme's folder
2. In your theme's `functions.php` file, register the fields :

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):
  $fields = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'my_acf_fields.php' ), true );

  acf_add_local_field_group( $fields );
endif;
```

Of course, if you have multiple files, you could write a function that loads all files contained in a directory and call `acf_add_local_field_group()` for each of them.

Comment: Yeah, this worked perfectly Manu, thanks. I was expecting some other form of confirmation when I had initially done this, but I can see that it is reading the files now that I've deleted the custom fields from the CMS. Thanks again!